# Check which specific validation failed for a model - ActiveModel Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, activemodel

I have a problem in Rails, with ActiveModel error messages.

My question is: "Is it possible to know from which condition specifically an error has been generated when I validate and ActiveModel element?"

Let me explain the situation:

I am creating a "forgot password" page.

The form takes only a field: the email of the user, that must be present and have the format of an email.

I created an ActiveModel to validate the form:

```
class ForgetPasswordSubmission

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Serialization

  validates :email, presence: true, email: { id: "not_email", message: "Please enter a valid email."}

 attr_accessor :attributes

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    @attributes = attributes
  end

  def read_attribute_for_validation(key)
    @attributes[key]
  end

end
```

In my controller, I call:
submission = ForgetPasswordSubmission.new(email: params[:email])

and then, I check if it is valid: submission.valid?

If not valid, I can have two errors messages:

1 - If the field is empty

2 - If the format of the email is not good

I would like to be able to know specifically which one of these messages is present, because I want to show the errors differently in the view.

My problem here is that submission.errors.messages[:email] is a symbol that will show:
["can't be blank", "Please enter a valid email."]
or
["Please enter a valid email."]
or
["can't be blank"]
depending on the situation.

I don't want to check like that:

submission.errors.messages.each do |v|
   if v == "Please enter a valid email" ...
   elsif ...
because changing my error message will break the test. I would rather make a test on a parameter that will not change.

So my question is: Is there a way to test if the error message comes from
presence:true
or 
email:true

in my model?

Thanks a lot for your help!

EDIT:
The solution I found thanks to Laurence was to add a method to my model:

```
def good_email_format?

    if !@attributes[:email].present?
        return false
    elsif @attributes[:email].present? && !@attributes[:email].valid?
        return false
    else
        return true
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you use the "present?" method to test if its present.

```
user.email.present?
```

And then use the "valid?" method to test the other validation.

```
user.email.valid?
```

Otherwise, you can write a method in your model to do that test. Something like:

```
def is_email_blank?
  self.email.blank?
end
```

And then do your logic like this:

```
if user.is_email_blank?
  [logic]
else
  [logic]
end
```

Good luck.

Comment: You helped me find a solution.

As you advised, I added a method in my model:
def good_email_format?
    if !@attributes[:email].present?
        return false
    elsif @attributes[:email].present? && !@attributes[:email].valid?
        return false
    else
        return true
    end

Comment: Glad it helped. And thank you for accepting my answer. It gives me enough reputation to post pictures now, haha.

Comment: Aha, I am also struggling with the low reputation. :)